# Import in QGIS a XML with metadata and a reference to the attribute information ISO 19115

Tags: qgis, metadata, iso-19115, iso-19110

I have created an XML file containing metadata for a specific layer. The XML is
in ISO 19115/ISO 19139. I have also added attribute information (based on ISO19110) as a reference.

```
<gmd:contentInfo> 
 <gmd:includedWithDataset>
   <gco:Boolean>0</gco:Boolean>
 </gmd:includedWithDataset>
 <gmd:MD_FeatureCatalogueDescription>
   <gmd:featureCatalogueCitation xlink:href="http://########:####/layers/path/feature_catalogue"/>
 </gmd:MD_FeatureCatalogueDescription>
```

I am trying to upload this metadata file in my layer on QGIS using the
MetaTools plugin. Most of the metadata (title, abstract etc.) are uploaded
correctly but all the attribute information described in the "feature_catalogue" are not loaded.

As it can be seen in the screenshot the Content Information section is empty.

[image]

Is there a way to upload metadata in a layer in QGIS and include also the
feature's attributes?

Comment: I added ISO 19139, as this is the XML encoding of ISO 19115/19119.